# How to compare object type with boolean

Tags: java

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class file{
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Object a;
        a = true;
        if (a == true){
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error error: incomparable types: Object and boolean

I was to compare object a which stores a boolean value with an actual boolean type. How do I do that?

Comment: Cast it to Boolean. May I ask why you need something like this in the first place.

Comment: I have a hashmap in which the value is not of a fixed data type. So my hashmap looks like <String, Object>. The hashmap is going to be fixed and for a certain key I know that the object will be boolean. I want to check if its true or not

Comment: Smells like a bad design to me.

Comment: Yeah it is, its just a proof of concept and we don't want to disturb the existing code much.

Answer (score 6):

This happens because `boolean` primitive `true` is *boxed* for conversion to `Object`. You need to compare it to another boxed object, like this

```
if (a == Boolean.TRUE) {
    ...
}
```

or like this

```
if (a.equals(true)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing an Object reference to a primitive boolean - the types are not compatible for the equality operator (`==`).  You should generally avoid using `==` with objects unless you really want to check if it is the same reference.

Prefer the `equals` method to compare objects.

```
if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(a)) { ... do stuff ... }
```

Note that we are invoking the method on a statically defined instance and passing the variable to be tested as the argument.  The method will handle null arguments and incorrect type arguments (it will return false) so you don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -
if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(a)) { ... }